# Android Studio listFiles returns null with assets folder

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, assets, filereader

In the assets folder I have another folder called songs with .txt files. I've been trying to put all .txt files in a File[ ] but I get a NullPointer on folder.listFiles().

Here's the code :

```
    File folder = new File("assets/songs");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();


    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[i];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
            this.list.add(content);
            System.out.println(content);
        }
    }

    return this.list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assets are not files on the device. They are files on the development machine. They are entries inside the APK file on the device.

Use `AssetManager` to work with assets, including [its `list()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

As sir @CommonsWare mentioned, you can use AssetManager like this:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

Note that this `file` is String array. So don't forget to initialize new file for each element of the array before iterating over it.